# Error in wordpress function.php file

Tags: php, wordpress, function, wordpress-theming

I am trying to add a particular shortcode to my theme, but i get an error when i paste the below code in my themes function.php. I already tried `including once` in the function.php but that did not work.

I think the problem is because of the `<?php` prefix and `?>` suffix it has which is prohibited in wordpress fucntion.php. I had removed all `<?php` and `?>` but it still generates an error.

```
// Add Shortcode
function acardio_big_grid_1() {

  <div class="col-md-12 featt big-grid">
    <div class="container-fluid no-padding">

    <?php
    $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
    $args = array('post_type' => 'post', 'posts_per_page' => 5, 'paged' => $paged);
    $query = new WP_Query($args);
    if( $query->have_posts() ) :
    while( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post(); ?>
<?php $count++; ?>
<?php if ($count == 1) : ?>




                <div class="big-pane col-xs-6">
                <div class="the-big-pane image">
                <div class="img-responsive"> <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) : ?>
        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail('big-grid-one-image'); ?></a>
    <?php else : ?>
        <img src="



<?php if (function_exists('get_option_tree') ) : if (get_option_tree('defualt_fatured_uploader')) :  ?>

        <?php get_option_tree( 'defualt_fatured_uploader', '', 'true' ); ?>
        <?php else : ?>

        <?php echo get_template_directory_uri (); ?>/img/nothumb-featured.png

    <?php endif; endif; ?>


        " />


    <?php endif; ?></div>
                </div>
                <div class="big-pane overlay">

                  <div class="the-big-pane-content">
                   <div class="the-cont-cat">
   <span class="the-content-cat-bt">  <?php $category = get_the_category(); if ($category) 
                    { echo wp_kses_post('<a href="' . get_category_link( $category[0]->term_id ) . '" class="tiptipBlog" title="' . sprintf( esc_html__( "View all posts in %s", "acardio" ), $category[0]->name ) . '" ' . '>' . $category[0]->name.'</a> ');}  ?></span>  <span class="the-content-cat-bt"> <?php taqyeem_get_score(); ?> </span>
  </div>
                    <h1><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php echo wp_trim_words( get_the_title(), 15 ); ?></a></h1>
                    <span class="the-content-post-data"><span class="the-auth-post-image-content" style="padding-top: 0px !important;"> <?php echo get_avatar( get_the_author_meta( 'user_email' ), 100 ); ?> </span> By <a href="#"><?php the_author_posts_link(); ?></a> <span class="the-content-post-date"> <i class="fa fa-clock-o the-content "></i><?php the_time('jS M, Y') ?></span> </span>
                  </div>
                </div>
                </div>


                <?php elseif ($count == 2) : ?>  
                <div class="small-pane-holder1 col-xs-6">
                <div class="small-pane col-xs-6 one">
                <div class="the-small-pane-image">
                <?php the_post_thumbnail();?>
                </div>
                  <div class="small-pane-overlay">
                    <div class="small-pan-content">
                     <div class="the-cont-cat">
   <span class="the-content-cat-bt">  <?php $category = get_the_category(); if ($category) 
                    { echo wp_kses_post('<a href="' . get_category_link( $category[0]->term_id ) . '" class="tiptipBlog" title="' . sprintf( esc_html__( "View all posts in %s", "acardio" ), $category[0]->name ) . '" ' . '>' . $category[0]->name.'</a> ');}  ?></span>  <span class="the-content-cat-bt"> <?php taqyeem_get_score(); ?> </span>
  </div>
  <h1 class="small-pane-title"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php echo wp_trim_words( get_the_title(), 10 ); ?></a></h1>

                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>

                <?php elseif ($count == 3) : ?>
                <div class="small-pane col-xs-6 two">
                <div class="the-small-pane-image">
                <?php the_post_thumbnail();?>
                </div>
                  <div class="small-pane-overlay">
                    <div class="small-pan-content">
                     <div class="the-cont-cat">
   <span class="the-content-cat-bt">  <?php $category = get_the_category(); if ($category) 
                    { echo wp_kses_post('<a href="' . get_category_link( $category[0]->term_id ) . '" class="tiptipBlog" title="' . sprintf( esc_html__( "View all posts in %s", "acardio" ), $category[0]->name ) . '" ' . '>' . $category[0]->name.'</a> ');}  ?></span>  <span class="the-content-cat-bt"> <?php taqyeem_get_score(); ?> </span>
  </div>
  <h1 class="small-pane-title"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php echo wp_trim_words( get_the_title(), 10 ); ?></a></h1>

                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>

                <?php elseif ($count == 4) : ?> 
                <div class="small-pane col-xs-6 three">
                <div class="the-small-pane-image">
                <?php the_post_thumbnail();?>
                </div>
                  <div class="small-pane-overlay">
                    <div class="small-pan-content">
                     <div class="the-cont-cat">
   <span class="the-content-cat-bt">  <?php $category = get_the_category(); if ($category) 
                    { echo wp_kses_post('<a href="' . get_category_link( $category[0]->term_id ) . '" class="tiptipBlog" title="' . sprintf( esc_html__( "View all posts in %s", "acardio" ), $category[0]->name ) . '" ' . '>' . $category[0]->name.'</a> ');}  ?></span>  <span class="the-content-cat-bt"> <?php taqyeem_get_score(); ?> </span>
  </div>
  <h1 class="small-pane-title"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php echo wp_trim_words( get_the_title(), 10 ); ?></a></h1>

                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>

                <?php elseif ($count == 5) : ?> 
                <div class="small-pane col-xs-6 four">
                <div class="the-small-pane-image">
                <?php the_post_thumbnail();?>
                </div>
                  <div class="small-pane-overlay">
                    <div class="small-pan-content">
                     <div class="the-cont-cat">
   <span class="the-content-cat-bt">  <?php $category = get_the_category(); if ($category) 
                    { echo wp_kses_post('<a href="' . get_category_link( $category[0]->term_id ) . '" class="tiptipBlog" title="' . sprintf( esc_html__( "View all posts in %s", "acardio" ), $category[0]->name ) . '" ' . '>' . $category[0]->name.'</a> ');}  ?></span>  <span class="the-content-cat-bt"> <?php taqyeem_get_score(); ?> </span>
  </div>
  <h1 class="small-pane-title"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php echo wp_trim_words( get_the_title(), 10 ); ?></a></h1>

                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>

    </div>  



<?php else : ?>

  <?php endif; ?>
<?php endwhile; ?>
<?php endif; ?>

</div>
</div>
}
add_shortcode( 'acardio-big-grid-1', 'acardio_big_grid_1' );
```

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: Cleaned up noise in the question. Please consider cleaning up your code indentation to make this easier to read.

Answer (score 0):

Right near the top you have a syntax error - an issue with your PHP tags. You need a closing php tag before the HTML, and an opening PHP tag after. The top of the code should read like so:

```
function acardio_big_grid_1() {

?>
  <div class="col-md-12 featt big-grid">
    <div class="container-fluid no-padding">

<?php
$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
$args = array('post_type' => 'post', 'posts_per_page' => 5, 'paged' => $paged);
```

You have a similar problem near the end of the code sample, but this time missing a opening php tag:

```
<?php endwhile; ?>
<?php endif; ?>

</div>
</div>

<?php
    }
add_shortcode( 'acardio-big-grid-1', 'acardio_big_grid_1' );
```

No guarantees that that is all your issues, but that would be one key issue in the code sample you provided.

Comment: hello, thanks so much, i wouldn't have been able to do this without you, i wonder how you saw those and i don't.

Comment: You bet @johnpink! I teach coding, and have a lot of practice scanning for syntax errors -- always look around HMTL, because it is easy to forget those tags. Typical practice on this site is to "accept" the answer if it helped you. You might also check out coding environments that have error checking -- there are a lot available.